# Powershell Start-Process for a remote machine not working

Tags: powershell, jenkins, start-process

**remotePSExecuter.ps1 file:**

```
$InputArgs=$args[0]
$Username=$args[1]
$Password=$args[2]
$ComputerName=$args[3]
$PSToExecute=$args[4]
write-host $Username $Password $ComputerName $PSToExecute
$SecurePassWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" $Username, $SecurePassWord
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -credential $Cred
$DownloadInstallJob = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -filepath "${PSToExecute}" -ArgumentList "${InputArgs}"
echo $DownloadInstallJob
Remove-PSSession -Session $Session
```

**downloadInstallWinVcops.ps1 file:**

```
$buildId=$args[0]
$storageDir = "C:\vcops-downloads"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$url = "http://build-squid.com/build/mts/release/${buildId}/publish/Web_Installers/InstData/Windows/VM/file.exe"
write-host url=$url
write-host downloading windows vcops build ${buildId} ...
$file = "$storageDir\winvcops.exe"
$webclient.DownloadFile($url,$file)
write-host downloading windows vcops finished!
write-host installing windows vcops...
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\vcops-downloads\winvcops.exe" -ArgumentList "-i silent" -wait
write-host windows vcops installation finished!
```

This is the way I am calling on Jenkins machine:

```
.\EnterpriseAdapters/remotePSExecuter.ps1 sb-xxxx Administrator password 10.xx.xx.xx EnterpriseAdapters/downloadInstallWinVcops.ps1
```

Problem:
`Start-Process -FilePath "C:\vcops-downloads\winvcops.exe" -ArgumentList "-i silent" -wait` is not getting called on remote machine.

Comment: Try using the absolute file-path and check the result.

Comment: Download is working fine on remote machine.

Comment: The problem here is I think is "Start-Process" command is not executing on remote machine.

Comment: Did you try with the absolute file-path?

Comment: Yes I tried that also.

Comment: .\EnterpriseAdapters/remotePSExecuter.ps1 sb-xxxx Administrator password 10.xx.xx.xx Administrator password C:/JenkinsWorkspace/setupAdapterEnv_SingleSliceWin/EnterpriseAdapters/downloadInstallWinVcops.ps1

Comment: You missed specifying full path for EnterpriseAdapters/remotePSExecuter.ps1 . Try this once, if still it doesn't work, please post the console log on your jenkins build.

Comment: That too did't worked. Jenkins log: Administrator password 10.xx.xx.xx C:\JenkinsWorkspace\setupAdapterEnv_SingleSliceWin\EnterpriseAdapters\downloadInstallWinVcops.ps1
url=http://build-squid.com/build/mts/release/sb-xxxx/publish/Web_Installers/InstData/Windows/VM/file.exe
downloading windows vcops build sb-xxxx ...
downloading windows vcops finished!
installing windows vcops...
windows vcops installation finished!
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Hey Akhil, Do you know any other command which can install my exe silently? Which can be used there.

Comment: It's not clear how you've come to the conclusion it is not running the Start-Process command. Is there some output or log file you are checking? There is an open bug with the [-Wait parameter in remote sessions.](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/774903/powershell-3-0-start-process-disregards-wait-parameter-when-invoked-remotely) Also, is it possible you are running into a double hop issue? In the default authentication mechanism, credentials are not flowed to the remote session so your ability to connect to other systems is restricted.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025062/windows-start-command-not-working-from-jenkins-pipeline
short explanation if the problem is the same: Jenkins is running as a windows service and as such it cannot create a new console window